# Topology: Prove that every closed subset C of A is also closed in X iff A is closed in X

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm having a very hard time constructing proofs in my introductory topology course. Here is one that seems like it would be simple, but have no clue where to begin:

Let $X$ be a space, $A \subseteq X$ a subspace. Prove that every closed subset $C \subseteq A$ is also closed in $X$ iff $A$ is closed in $X$

I know that to prove the ($\implies$) direction, I need to show that $A$ is closed. I also know that since $A$ is a subspace and $C \subseteq A$ is closed, then there is a closed subset $B \subseteq X$ such that $C=A \cap B$. From here, I'm at a loss. I was thinking I could somehow use the definition of the subspace topology of $A$ since it is defined to be $\{U \cap A| U \in \mathcal{T}\}$, but that is just a guess. Am I going the right direction with this?

Thank you!

Comment: The $\rightarrow$ direction is pretty trivial, since $A$ is a closed subset of $A$ (since $\varnothing$ is an open subset of $A$), and thus, $A$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s look at the other direction first. Suppose that $A$ is closed. We want to show that if $C$ is closed in $A$, then $C$ is closed in $X$, so there’s an obvious place to start:

> Suppose that $C\subseteq A$ is closed in $A$.

What does that tell us? About the only tool that we have handy seems to be the definition of the subspace topology, so let’s see what it says:

> Then there is an $F\subseteq X$ such that $F$ is closed in $X$, and $C=F\cap A$.

We want to show that $C$ is closed in $X$, and all we really know about it is that $C$ is the intersection of the sets $F$ and $A$, so what do we know about *them*? They’re both closed in $X$. And that does it:

> $F$ and $A$ are closed in $X$, so their intersection $C$ is closed in $X$. $C$ was an arbitrary closed set in $A$, so every subset of $A$ that is closed in $A$ is also closed in $X$. $\dashv$

This is a ‘follow-your-nose’ proof: there is one very natural, straightforward thing to try, and it works. As you progress, you’ll run into more and more proofs that require actual ingenuity, proofs that you cannot find simply by ‘following your nose’, but you should still keep your eyes open for the ones like this that practically lead you by the hand.

Now suppose that every $C\subseteq A$ that is closed in $A$ is also closed in $X$; we want to show that $A$ is closed in $X$. This direction is actually just a little less straightforward. Still, it seems very natural to ask what information about $A$ would let us conclude that it is closed in $X$, and our hypothesis tells us: it would immediately let us conclude that $A$ is closed in $X$ if we knew that $A$ was closed in $A$; is this the case? Well, $A=X\cap A$, and $X$ is closed in $X$, so $A$ is closed in $A$ by the definition of the subspace topology, and we’re done. Having discovered the argument, we could write it up like this, for instance:

> Suppose that every $C\subseteq A$ that is closed in $A$ is also closed in $X$. $X$ is closed in $X$ so $A=X\cap A$ is closed in $A$ by the definition of the subspace topology, and therefore $A$ is closed in $X$.

Note that we could just as well have used $\operatorname{cl}_XA$ instead of $X$: $\operatorname{cl}_XA$ is closed in $X$, so $A=A\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA$ is closed in $A$ and therefore (by our hypothesis) in $X$. Any closed subset of $X$ that contains $A$ would work; $X$ and $\operatorname{cl}_XA$ are just the two on which we can easily lay our hands, and they could in some cases be the only ones that exist.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but wow your answer was very insightful, thank you so much! Just to clarify, for the forward direction, we can conclude that A is closed in X since A is an intersection of two closed sets, right?

Comment: @RandyButternubs: You’re very welcome. Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much

Comment: @RandyButternubs: My pleasure!